# pyembed does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use [pyembed](https://github.com/pyembed/pyembed) with Python3.3.1 in my virtual environment.

```
$ pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
pyembed==1.3.1
requests==2.9.1
```

But the problem is, I get Traceback instead of valid html code. As an example:

```
>>> from pyembed.core import PyEmbed
>>> html = PyEmbed().embed('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jazz/workspace/pillow/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyembed/core/__init__.py", line 59, in embed
oembed_urls, max_width=max_width, max_height=max_height)
  File "/home/jazz/workspace/pillow/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyembed/core/consumer.py", line 57, in get_first_oembed_response
raise PyEmbedConsumerError('No valid OEmbed responses for URLs %s' % oembed_urls)
pyembed.core.consumer.PyEmbedConsumerError: No valid OEmbed responses for URLs <generator object get_oembed_urls at 0xb724b5a4>
>>>
```

I get this Traceback with any valid youtube link. The strange thing is, it worked yesterday... Any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Youtube is blocking the default user-agent for pyembed:

```
In [7]: requests.get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
Out[7]: <Response [503]>

In [8]: headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' }

In [9]: requests.get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0', headers=headers)
Out[9]: <Response [200]>
```

Comment: The issue is solved by pyembed==1.3.3 and everything works fine now.